# How to copy folders to specific folder in powershell?

Tags: powershell, window

I want to copy a folder which contain many file and other folders to a specific folder. However I get fail by using the following code.

```
    Copy-Item "c:\F1" "c:\Fs\F1"
or
    Copy-Item "c:\F1\*" "c:\Fs\F1"
```

The structure of folder1:

```
F1
  F1-1
       file B
  F1-2
       file C
       file D
  file A
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably missing the -recurse option.

```
Copy-Item -Path C:\F1 -Destination c:\FsF1 –Recurse
```